# Where can I read more about the demonic tattoos from Mortal Remains?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, hunter-the-vigil, demon-the-descent

In Mortal Remains, on p124 it discusses Fiendish Flaws.

> - A tattoo-like glyph on the demon’s forearm that’s visible
>     through clothing.

I presume this is a Demon the Descent thing, but searching for tattoo in the pdf hasn't helped me. What is it and where can I read more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are Glitches, specifically Brands, Glitches starts on p184 of Demon the Descent

> Glitches can emerge from two primary sources: Primum
>   and Cover. Changes in either of these qualities cause them
>   manifest. Glitches fall into one of two categories: transient
>   or permanent. Transient glitches last only a short while (as
>   dictated by the demon’s Primum), while permanent ones
>   endure indefinitely.
>
> **Causes of Transient Glitches**
>
> - Succeeding on a compromise roll (optional)
> - Dramatic failure during Installation (p. 188)
> - Going loud (p. 195)
> - Use the demon’s “loud” Primum rating, 10, when
>     determining the type, severity, and duration of this glitch.
>
> **Causes of Permanent Glitches**
>
> - Primum increases or decreases
> - Failure or dramatic failure on a compromise roll
>     (optional)